# Search for a text file within multiple folders

Tags: search, vbscript

I'm trying to create my first VBS script and I'm lost. I need to be able to search for a specific text  within 4 network paths. Basically this is 4 separate LOG files that only hold text files, no sub-directories or anything.  I would like if the text was found in whichever network path it would only bring that path up and not allow the rest to come up. The name of the text file should be user input driven. However the code below doesn't work and I'm not sure why..

Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction? Or help me out? I was able to open up the network path but not sure how to do the rest: Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim fso, folder, file
Dim folderName, searchFileName, renameFileTo

' Parameters
folderName     = "\\servername\c$\Program Files (x86)\LOGS"
searchFileName = "number_SUMMARY.txt"


' Create filesystem object and the folder object
' how the FSO works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

' Loop over all files in the folder until the searchFileName is found
For each file In folder.Files    
    ' See if the file starts with the name we search
    ' how instr works: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_instr.asp
    If instr(file.name, searchFileName) = 1 Then
        result = MsgBox ("You Found it!", _
    vbAbortRetryIgnore+vbExclamation+vbDefaultButton2, "You Found it")
    Exit For
     End If
Next
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Work on your specs. Do you want to look for a file x.txt at four specific locations that happen to be network pathes? Or do you need to find one or more (the first?) x.txt in any subdirs of those four folders? How do you paln to get the user's input?
2. For efficiency and easy of use I'd avoid "Shell.Application" when "Scripting.FileSystemObject" works. If you need a recursive search, consider shelling out to `dir /s /b`.
3. (At least): Do a bit research wrt 'check for existence of a file' and put some more code into your question.

Comment: I added some additional code but it doesn't run.. it won't throw me an error.. @Ekkehard.Horner